# How to display 3 post per slide

Tags: loop

I need to  create a sliders contain 3 post title for each slide.
I can create it by one title for each slide but not 3 posts
Could you please help me
This is My code

```
  <ul class="overview">
       <?php 
            $newspost = new WP_Query();
             newspost->query('cat=10&showposts=6&post_type=page'); 
          while ($newspost->have_posts()) : $newspost->the_post(); 
          ?>
               <li>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                   <p class="testimonial_name"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                  </a>   
               </li>
  <?php    endwhile;?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: <ul class="overview"><?php 
 $newspost = new WP_Query();
        newspost->query('cat=10&showposts=6&post_type=page'); 
while ($newspost->have_posts()) : $newspost->the_post();  ?>
<li>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
 <p class="testimonial_name"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </a>   
</li>
<?php   endwhile;?></ul>

Comment: Please edit your question and update with your code. Do not post in comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are two popular solutions for this. You can:

**Alternative 1:**

Add a counter to the while, and do something special if the counter reaches 3:

```
$i = 0;
while(...) {
  $i++;
  if ($i == 3) {
    ...
    $i = 0;
  }
}
```

This is difficult to do here because you will probably end up with an empty or unclosed `li`.

**Alternative 2:**

Use `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query` ([probably what you should use anyway](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)). 
Use `array_chunk` to split the array of posts into chunks.

Comment: `get_posts()` uses `WP_Query`, so it actually doesn't really matter. The only advantage is that `get_posts()` is a bit faster due to the use of `'no_found_rows' => true` :-)

Comment: How did you test it?

Comment: @BradDalton I'm not sure if this is directed at me, so I will answer according to my comment. Add a timer before and after the query and subtract the two times from each other. You'll see that `get_posts` is faster as pagination is legally broken and skipped by `get_posts`. This is all done by `'no_found_rows' => true`. Just a tip, if you need to address someone specific, use the @ sign and the person's name, otherwise only the answerer and question asker gets the message, not the other participants :-)

Comment: Sorry yes @goose, forgot your name! haha. Thanks for the useful answer